# Undefined error with await message reaction in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I was trying to make it so when you choose a specific reaction it sends a message to a channel about you reaction. The reactions are added but when I react it returns an error saying that that emoji is undefined. When I console logged the `collected.first()` returned as undefined.

```
            message.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == message.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == '1️⃣' || reaction.emoji.name == '2️⃣' || reaction.emoji.name == '3️⃣' || reaction.emoji.name == '4️⃣' || reaction.emoji.name == '5️⃣'),
            { max: 1, time: 10000 }).then(collected => {

                console.log(collected.first())

                if (collected.first().emoji.name == '1️⃣') {

                    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(`764829720729747486`);
                    message.channel.send(`Successfully bought ${one}`)
                    channel.send(`<@${user.id}> Bought ${one}`).then(message => {
                        message.react('✅').then(r => {
                            message.react('❎');
                        });
                        message.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id === '610294687701532691' && (reaction.emoji.name === '✅' || reaction.emoji.name === '❎'),
                            { max: 1, time: 86400000 }).then(collected => {
                                if (collected.first().emoji.name === '✅') {
                                    user.send('Order Accepted')
                                } else if (collected.first().emoji.name === '❎') {
                                    user.send('Order Declined')
                                }
                            })

                    })

                } else if (collected.first().emoji.name == '2️⃣') {

                    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(`764829720729747486`);
                    message.channel.send(`Successfully bought ${tow}`)
                    channel.send(`<@${user.id}> Bought ${tow}`).then(message => {
                        message.react('✅').then(r => {
                            message.react('❎');
                        });
                        message.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id === '610294687701532691' && (reaction.emoji.name === '✅' || reaction.emoji.name === '❎'),
                            { max: 1, time: 86400000 }).then(collected => {
                                if (collected.first().emoji.name === '✅') {
                                    user.send('Order Accepted')
                                } else if (collected.first().emoji.name === '❎') {
                                    user.send('Order Declined')
                                }
                            })

                    })

                } else if (collected.first().emoji.name == '3️⃣') {

                    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(`764829720729747486`);
                    message.channel.send(`Successfully bought ${tho}`)
                    channel.send(`<@${user.id}> Bought ${tho}`).then(message => {
                        message.react('✅').then(r => {
                            message.react('❎');
                        });
                        message.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id === '610294687701532691' && (reaction.emoji.name === '✅' || reaction.emoji.name === '❎'),
                            { max: 1, time: 86400000 }).then(collected => {
                                if (collected.first().emoji.name === '✅') {
                                    user.send('Order Accepted')
                                } else if (collected.first().emoji.name === '❎') {
                                    user.send('Order Declined')
                                }
                            })

                    })

                } else if (collected.first().emoji.name == '4️⃣') {

                    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(`764829720729747486`);
                    message.channel.send(`Successfully bought ${fo}`)
                    channel.send(`<@${user.id}> Bought ${fo}`).then(message => {
                        message.react('✅').then(r => {
                            message.react('❎');
                        });
                        message.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id === '610294687701532691' && (reaction.emoji.name === '✅' || reaction.emoji.name === '❎'),
                            { max: 1, time: 86400000 }).then(collected => {
                                if (collected.first().emoji.name === '✅') {
                                    user.send('Order Accepted')
                                } else if (collected.first().emoji.name === '❎') {
                                    user.send('Order Declined')
                                }
                            })

                    })

                } else if (collected.first().emoji.name == '5️⃣') {

                    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(`764829720729747486`);
                    message.channel.send(`Successfully bought ${fif}`)
                    channel.send(`<@${user.id}> Bought ${fif}`).then(message => {
                        message.react('✅').then(r => {
                            message.react('❎');
                        });
                        message.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id === '610294687701532691' && (reaction.emoji.name === '✅' || reaction.emoji.name === '❎'),
                            { max: 1, time: 86400000 }).then(collected => {
                                if (collected.first().emoji.name === '✅') {
                                    user.send('Order Accepted')
                                } else if (collected.first().emoji.name === '❎') {
                                    user.send('Order Declined')
                                }
                            })

                    })

                }

            }).catch(err => {
                message.reply(' Error')
                console.log(err)
            })
```

Comment: try `collected[0]` instead arrays count from 0 -- If that doesn't work try defining a new const `const first = collected.shift()`

Comment: I tried both they return the same error | It also said collected.shift() is not a function

Comment: @JonathanStevens `collected` is a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection), not an array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not treating [`time`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/CollectorOptions) as an [`error`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/AwaitReactionsOptions). As it is currently, after 10 seconds, the promise will resolve with a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) regardless of how many reactions were collected. You're getting this error because [`Collection.prototype.first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=first) will obviously return `undefined` on an empty collection.

If you'd like the promise to *reject* after the time is up (execute the `catch` function), you have to add an additional option to the [`Message.prototype.awaitReactions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions) function.

Also, you can compact your filter function by simply creating an array of possible emoji names and checking it against the current emoji name once.

```js
message
 .awaitReactions(
  (reaction, user) =>
   user.id == message.author.id &&
   ['1️⃣', '2️⃣', '3️⃣', '4️⃣', '5️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name),
  { max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ['time'] } // errors: ['time'] - reject after time is up
 )
 .then('...')
 .catch('...');
```